# Silverlight: How to databind on a condition

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl object and am setting the DataTemplate to hold a Grid with a couple controls in it. The controls are databoud to a collection of some object MyObj, specifically a TextBlock and a ComboBox. MyObj has its own collection inside of it for a property. If that property has only 1 object in its collection, only the TextBlock is visible. But if there is more than 1 object in the collection, the TextBlock is visible and the ComboBox becomes visible once the TextBlock is clicked on.

I have the ComboBox filled up with what it needs, I just can't figure out how to specify which ComboBox needs to become visible when the TextBlock is Clicked on.

I guess my question is, how would I even go about doing this? Or, is there a better way to think about this problem?

I'm new to databinding in Silverlight and running into a bunch of issues on my own. Any help is always appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you mean here? "I have the ComboBox filled up with what it needs, I just can't figure out how to specify which ComboBox needs to become visible when the TextBlock is Clicked on."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you could do is add an extra property to the data item that you binding to, something like 'IsSelectionAvailable'. Make the visibility of your combobox bound to this property (via a boolean to Visibility enum Value Converter). Finally, add a click event handler for the text box that sets the IsSelectionAvailable property to true for the object it is bound to.

Hope that helps.